# MySql; how do you find time between two queries and sort them by least time

Tags: mysql, time, between

I have the following question to answer:

> For each tag, retrieve the 10 to-dos with quickest completion time (i.e. the time between the creation and the completion of the to-do)

I tried this

```
Select *
From ToDoItem, Tag, ItemTag
Where 
    time between CreationDate and 
    CompletionDate is ASC AND
    Tag.Id = ItemTag.ToDoId AND 
    ItemTag.TagId = ToDoItem.Id
Limit 10
```

So I first want to find the time between the creation date and completion date and after that I want them asc so it sorts them om time getting more, after that I select all the tags and at last I want to limit them to max 10.

But this doesn't work and I think the problem in somewhere in the "Time between `creationdate` and `CompletionDate`".

So the question I have is the following:

How do you find the time between two different tables with dates in it?

[Description of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZevH.png)

Comment: your question needs some serious formating to be understood and it seems that your are asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: please include the definition of the tables TAG, ITEMTAG and TODOITEM otherwise is very hard to help you.

Comment: This seems like a homework question. In addition to that, I suggest you supply all pertinent details when asking a question, in this case, some example data and/or tables might help.

Comment: Please providw table structure

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 issues with your query:

1. You need to use `datediff()` function to get the time between.
2. Ordering the results ahould be done with `order by` statement, not in the where part.

   ```
   Select *
   From ToDoItem, Tag, ItemTag
   Where   
     Tag.Id = ItemTag.ToDoId AND 
     ItemTag.TagId = ToDoItem.Id
   Order by datediff(completiontime, creationtime) asc
   Limit 10
   ```